# How to access NSMutableArray from my FirstViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I was able to parse a JSON and stored it in a `NSMutableArray` named as json in my `FirstViewController`. The problem is, I do not know how to access the array in my `FirstViewController` from my View Controllers.

**EDIT!!!**

I moved the code from AppDelegate to my FirstViewController as it is not a good practice.

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *jsonData;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *jsonData;

@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
@synthesize jsonData;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=coredata"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondViewController.secondJSON = [self jsonData];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *secondJSON;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *secondJSON;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@", [self secondJSON]);
}
```

**Output**

```
2013-02-03 00:16:17.749 Subscription[24669:c07] (null)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: u want to pass array from one viewccontroller to another ??

Comment: Yes, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] json]`?

(And please, ***don't send synchronous requests on the main thread while the application is launching!***)

Comment: @Jahm because it blocks the main thread -> freezes the UI. **NEVER EVER** do networking on the main thread. Also, you can express your appreciation by accepting my answer.

Comment: Glad to asked this question! I moved it to my first view controller!

Comment: @Jahm I don't think that's already good. View controllers are, again, part of the UI. You should either send an async request pr move the networking code to a separate threas manually.

Comment: @Jahm Anywhere, just wrap it into an `NSThread` or a block executed by `dyspatch_async()`, or even better, use `+ [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:]`.

Comment: So can I just put sendAsynchronousRequest: to my view controller?

Comment: @Jahm Yes, but please start looking up some documentation.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, if you are using ARC then change

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *json;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *json;
```

as retain makes your abject reference to weak.

Second to access in your viewcontroller use

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//appDelegate.json //Your Array
```

Why don't you implement this method directly into your viewController, AppDelegate class should be as clean as possible.

Comment: Yeah I transferred it to my first view controller. The problem's the same, I can't access the array from my second and third view controller. I am using tabbed bar by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of Application Delegate in your desire view and call its objects.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableArray *arMyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[appDelegate.json mutableCopy]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
     AppDelegate *appobj =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     NSLog(@"%@",appobj.json);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view controller where you want to access json array, make instance of appdelegate like this :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

And after that access json array by using this instance varaible.

```
 NSMutableArray *arMyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithAaray:appdelegate.json];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `NSMutableArray *listOfData`  in your `SecondViewController` such like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    
    @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
    
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *listOfData;
    
    @end
```

and pass your `NSMutableArray *jsonData;` to `SecondViewController` when you navigate it.
(*At create object of SecondViewController*) such like,

**This code write in** `FirstViewController`

```
 SecondViewController *lvController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
 lvController.listOfData = self.jsonData;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvController animated:YES];
```

And Check it in `viewDidLoad` method of `SecondViewController` , such like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"My Data : %@", self.listOfData);
}
```

Comment: Where will I put this, `SecondViewController *lvController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
 lvController.listOfData = self.jsonData;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvController animated:YES];
`

Comment: I followed your code but when I proceed to my `SecondViewController`, it is a `null`.

Comment: at where you want to go on SecondViewController

Comment: It is a tabbed bar project, when I click on the second tab, it proceeds to the `SecondViewController` and its null.

Comment: then .. why u not send request from SecondViewController...it is more easy to solve it...thanks :)